# Referencing a page outside of latex build

Tags: thesis, ref

The wording of the title is not among my finest works, but let me explain my situation.

I am writing an introduction to my dissertation, which consists also of three peer-reviewed articles. These articles will be added to the final pdf document as they appeared in the journals, and thus the page numbering does not continue there (and they are not built along with my latex document of the introduction).

My question is: can I reference to a page on one of these articles (ie. outside my latex document) so that in the final, compiled document, clicking on a link would take the reader to the page I want?

Comment: In principle yes. It may take a little hackery. I'm assuming you are including the articles using `pdfpages`, it has some coptions to run commands on the included pages and one should be able to execute commands (like setting a label, remember `\phamsomsection`) on specific included pages. But you probably don't have any control over where on the page you land. So it might not be worth it in the long run.

Comment: Our phd students either choose to use the `pdfpages` route, perhaps with added toc elements but no further links into the included article. Or they choose to include the contents of each article as latex code with a separate title page, but now a normal part of the document and formatting.

Comment: @daleif you can have full controll over the location - you only need to move the \phantomsection at right place.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer sure, I call those ninjas, we tend to use them to delete headers and footers via tikz

Comment: @daleif The problem then becomes: how do I reference a page on one of these articles from within the introduction? I guess I can't really do that with \phantomsection, as I would put those in after compiling the intro (if I understood correctly)?

Comment: @Moppe We actually normally add a titlepage to each of the included articles and then just like to this title page. Here is an example of a student with included PDF articles and a separate title page for each. https://data.math.au.dk/publications/phd/2016/math-phd-2016-ita.pdf, this also shows the ninjas mentioned above where we remove certain headers and footers